# Linq and dictionary initialization

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Are these code blocks the same? Which one is better? Should I initialize the new dictionary at (2)?

```
XDocument docXml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
```

First block:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var temp = configXml.Root.Element("hs")
          .Descendants("h")
          .Select(x => new
          {
            a = x.Attribute("a").Value,
            b = x.Value
          });
          foreach (var c in temp)
          {
             dictionary.Add(c.a, c.b);
          }
```

Second block:

```
  ConectionStrings = configXml.Root.Element("hs")
                     .Descendants("h")
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("a").Value,
                                   x => x.Value);
```

Comment: What is `list`? The code blocks are quite different, so how should we compare them?

Comment: sorry, it just iterration from upper. I forgot change values at second code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes adding key by key or using `ToDictionary` are both the same.
You can see it by looking at .NET source code:

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TElement> 
          ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
          Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, 
          IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) 
{
     if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
     if (keySelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector");
     if (elementSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("elementSelector");
     Dictionary<TKey, TElement> d = new Dictionary<TKey, TElement>(comparer);
     foreach (TSource element in source) 
     {
         d.Add(keySelector(element), elementSelector(element));
     }
     return d;
}
```